# Dilemma in a swapping question - whose logic is correct?

Tags: python-3.x, function, arraylist

> Define a function SWAP(SCORES) to swap all those values in the list of SCORES, which are
> alternate elements.
> For example: If the SCORES contain [200, 456, 300, 100, 234, 678], the output should be displayed as [300, 200, 100, 456, 678, 234].

Now the pattern of arranging is kinda peculiar, since if [1,2,3,4,5,6] was the order, then the result was in the order [3,1,4,2,6,5].

```py
while True:
    l=eval(input('List: '))
    x=len(l)
    n=x//4
    t=4*n
    l1=l[:t]
    print(l1)
    l2=l[t:]
    print(l2)
    for i in range((len(l1)//2)):
        l1[i],l1[i+2]=l1[i+2],l1[i]
        #l1 shuffling over
    if len(l2)==1:
        l1+=l2
        print('Shuffled list:',l1)
    elif len(l2)>=2:
        l2=l2[::-1]
        l1+=l2
        print('Shuffled list:',l1)
    elif len(l2)==0:
        print('Shuffled list:',l1)
        #treating l2 separately
```

---

This was what I tried, and it did work well for me.

```py
================================== RESTART: C:/Users/Harikrishnan/OneDrive/Desktop/peculiar shuffling q.py ==================================
List: [200,456,300,100,234,678]
[200, 456, 300, 100]
[234, 678]
Shuffled list: [300, 100, 200, 456, 678, 234]
List: [1,2,3,4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[]
Shuffled list: [3, 4, 1, 2]
List: [1,2,3,4,5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5]
Shuffled list: [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
List: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
Shuffled list: [3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6, 5]
List: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[]
Shuffled list: [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 7, 8]
List: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Harikrishnan/OneDrive/Desktop/peculiar shuffling q.py", line 2, in <module>
    l=eval(input('List: '))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

My logic was: upto the 4n-th element, everything was fine. Odd position arguments were swapping, even position arguments were swapping, and after that four cases arose:

1. Nothing was left after the 4n elements.
2. 1 element was left,
3. 2 elements were left,
4. 3 elements were left.

---

My friend had another logic:

> i think the pattern is last two elements swapped, last third n last 5th, last 4th n last 6th, last 7 n last 10, last 8 n last 11, last 9 n last 12

Now I am confused. Who of us is right?

Comment: Only the person who wrote the original problem knows.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def swap(lst):
    l=len(lst)
    l2=list(lst)
    l3=[]
    if l<4:
        for i in range(len(l2)):
            if i+2<len(l2):
                l3.append(l2[i+2])
                l3.append(l2[i])
    elif l>4:
        l4=lst[:4]
        l5=lst[4:]
        for i in range(len(l4)):
            if i+2<len(l4):
                l3.append(l4[i+2])
                l3.append(l4[i])
        for i in range(0,len(l5)-1,2):
            l5[i],l5[i+1]=l5[i+1],l5[i]
            lst=l3+l6
    return lst
print(swap([200,456,300,100,234,678]))
print(swap([200,456,300,100,234,678,9,10,67,69]))
```

Output:
[300, 200, 100, 456, 678, 234]
[300, 200, 100, 456, 678, 234, 10, 9, 69, 67]

What the question mentioned was not an ordinary shuffle/alternate shuffle

Look at the image for understanding:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgw6u.jpg)

Here is my thought process:
For the first four elements, last two elements replace [n-2]th element
for the next consecutive terms, each term is swapped with next one continously
PS: All the best for exams broo!

Edit: Here is an improved code:

```
def swap(lst):
l3=[]
l4=lst[:4]
l5=lst[4:]

for i in range(len(l4)-2):
    l3.append(l4[i+2])
    l3.append(l4[i])
for i in range(0,len(l5)-1,2):
    l5[i],l5[i+1]=l5[i+1],l5[i]  
          
lst=l3+l5
return lst
```

print(swap([200,456,300,100,234,678]))